# How to use Actionscript 3.0 to go to a new Web Page at the last frame?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a SWF that is acting as a sort of intro for my site, when the intro is done playing, I would like it to go to a different site. How would I do this, and would I just put it in the actions panel of the last frame on the timeline? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3):

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("YOUR WEBSITE URL", "_self"))
```

docs: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to achieve this by calling JavaScript on the surrounding HTML page.